# Can we do better than Łukasiewicz's single axiom for implicational propositional logic?

Tags: propositional-calculus, axioms

Łukasiewicz's single axiom for implicational propositional calculus, $((p\to q)\to r)\to ((r\to p)\to (s\to p))$, is known to be the shortest possible. Does it also have the minimum number of propositional variables, or would it be possible to construct a single, most likely longer, axiom using just 3 propositional variables?

From the answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244594/number-of-distinct-variables-used-in-axiomatizating-classical-propositional-lo) question we get that at least one axiom with 3 variables is needed in order to fully capture implication, so it would be interesting to find out if this minimum can be achieved also with a single axiom.

Comment: Every single axiom with only a conditional and propositional variables listed in Appendix 1 of A. N. Prior's Formal Logic, 2nd edition 1962, has at least four variables (Lukasiewicz's axiom as the shortest has the same condition).  However, if we have functor-variables, there are three single axioms with two propositional variables, one functor-variable and C. A. Meredith;s paper of 1951 'On an Extended System of Propositional Calculus' credited for them: CδpCqδδq, CpCδqδδp, and CδpδδCqq.

Comment: Also, if we include propositional qunatifers Prior credits Meredith with another axiom with just one propositional variable and one functor-variable: CδδΠppδp.  'Π' is the Polish notation symbol for universal quantification.